# Using onBackPressed() and onSaveInstanceState() together in an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, state, android-fragmentactivity

I override onBackPressed like that, to

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

I also save one of my activity's fragment:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

However, these methods don't seem to work together (the state is never saved, though it worked well before I've overrode `onBackPressed()`).

Is there any way to fix it, except from using `SharedPreferences`? I would like to stick to `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to call

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

At the end of onBackPressed(). That way, when you press back button first is called onBackPressed, then it is called, in this order, onPause(), onStop(), onSaveInstanceState() and, finally, onDestroy().

Just a question about onBackPressed. **Why do you want to change the behaviour of back button?** Android know how to come back to previous activity!